Align vertices to fit a reference image
I actually need help with that. I modelled this mesh on the front view as I could not find a specific reference image to model the side view. I'm trying to model the side view as it shown in the pic but I basically having a hard time trying to align the vertices on this mesh, because it does not work properly as it's already modeled. My question is: is there an easy way or at least a way to curve the mesh or to align it so it fits the reference image on the side view? To make it more clear I am sharing my .blend file. Thanks in advance.

.blend... https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DBAevWxsj5IYvAEAK41Jasgi7jvJjQky/view?usp=sharing



hopefully this is helpful , I appreciate all of your help

Your file does not have images packed so nobody will be able to see what you are talking about. If you are talking about some images, it might be a good idea to add them to your question as well as well as screenshots to illustrate your problem so that people don't need to download the file just to understand the issue. You should edit the question, add images and reupload the file.

Hello, Games nr  .. The images you mention are central to the meaning of your post, and not included in the download.. Please edit to pack  your reference image, and share on https://blend-exchange.com/. Then the question will have meaning, and we can re-open it for you.

im really sorry for that late reply and thank u all for the reply , my fault again i will add and edit everything back , thank you for patient

Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", or "as seen in image", instead describe what the image illustrates. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

I can’t tell from the question… which is the reference image?

the first image I posted which is the side view , I'm sorry if my question is not really clear , As I don't know why my file does not contain the reference image

You can Pack images as suggested in my earlier comment.. for your file to be useful, we really need at least one, to demonstrate possible solutions.

sorry again im a bit noob sometimes i packed everything , if it does not work i will delete post and putting another thread so that i wont comment much , thanks in advance

Use Lattice with Proportional Editing. You can use multiple lattices by splitting the affected area with vertex groups.

